# PowerBuilder DataWindow object Edit

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have a DataWindow with some columns. One column contains numbers of a certain object. I want to put a Edit(mask?) on this column, so that when it is bigger than 0, change column value to "Available".

How can I Achieve this in design view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd delete the column (relax... deleting the column from the UI does not equate to deleting it from the data set) and replace it with a computed field with an expression something like:

```
if (col > 0, "Available", "Unavailable")
```

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: I ended up with 2 nested sums to get the amount and then set the String. Thanks anyway!